# Fluctuating css styles jquery and noscript

Tags: css

I have a script that has a jquery script controlling the css(init.js) and another noscript tag with the css files themselves. There are 3 css files for various screen dimensions
 However i realise this approach causes the css to keep fluctuating. E.g refresh causes font size to change, refresh again page changes back. The font itself also changes.

Anyone could suggest what may be an issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you loading the CSS via JavaScript rather than just including it from the page with <link rel="stylesheet">?

Comment: Hi there, i have solved this issue.